# PHP variable is printing type not content

Tags: php, arrays

i've stucked for a while with php..

In my code:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $max;$i++){
   if(//my condition){
       $job_found.= $obj[$i];
   }
   else{
       echo "jobs not found";
     }
   echo ($job_found);
}
```

When it gets a coincidence the results will be:

> Array

But if i try:

```
print_r ($obj[1]);
```

The result will be:

> Array ( [title] => my 2title [placement] => my placement [date] => my date [time] => My time [website] => http://www.g00gle.com )

How can i get the actual value of the array in that position and not just the type?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your code completely

Comment: `$obj[$i]` is an array so `$job_found` is an array, too.

Comment: paste your `array` also what is `$max`?

Comment: When you concatenate `something` with string, `something` becomes string too. String representation of array is word `Array`

Comment: try $job_found[]= $obj[$i]; And print_r($job_found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, as you can see from your own Post, `$obj[1]` is an Array, which means that all the Elements in the `$obj` variable are most likely Arrays as well. Unfortunately, you cannot just `echo` an Array but iterate through it to get the *echoable* data like so:

```
<?php

    $jobsHTML        = "";

    for($i = 0; $i < $max;$i++){
        if(!$jobsStillExist){       // CONDITION TO CHECK IF JOBS STILL EXIST
            echo "jobs not found";
            continue;
        }
        // SINCE, $obj[$i] COULD BE AN ARRAY,
        // YOU NEED TO CHECK THE TYPE 1ST. 
        // IF IT IS A STRING, APPEND IT AS A STRING TO $jobsHTML
        // OTHERWISE, LOOP THROUGH IT TO GET IT'S CONTENT...
        $foundJob   = $obj[$i];
        if(is_array($foundJob)){
            foreach($foundJob as $jobData){
                $jobsHTML .= $jobData["title"]                            . "<br />";
                $jobsHTML .= $jobData["placement"]                        . "<br />";
                $jobsHTML .= date("d/m/Y", strtotime($jobData["date"]))   . "<br />";
                $jobsHTML .= $jobData["time"]                             . "<br />";
                $jobsHTML .= $jobData["website"]                          . "<br /><br />";
            }
        }else if(is_string($foundJob)){
            $jobsHTML .= $foundJob                                        . "<br /><br />";
        }
    }

    echo ($jobsHTML);
```

Comment: Thanks man,im new at PHP and to me this is like the longest toString() ever.

Comment: @Jnewbie    LOL :-)  At some point in every venture, One **must** pass through the Pupil stage... and in time (with enough Devotion, Drive & Determination) move up & on to the Master stage. But then, that is what Growth is all about, right? Cheers & Good-Luck... PHP is Fun!!! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$job_found=array();
for($i = 0; $i < $max;$i++){
   if(//my condition){
       $job_found[]= $obj[$i];
   }
   else{
       echo "jobs not found";
     }
}

print_r($job_found);
```

Can you try like this.